# Can a set be described as "bijective"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Say we have a map $\phi$ with domain of definition $A$.

Suppose that $\phi$ gives a bijection between the two sets $A$ and $B$, but $\phi$ is not a bijection between $A$ and some other set $C$ (even though, it might be a well-defined map between them).

Is it then "acceptable" to describe $B$ as **$\phi$-bijective**, and $C$ as **non $\phi$-bijective**?

Comment: $B$ as $\phi$-bijective to $A$. But its not really standard terminology.

Comment: @Wuestenfux  Yes, thought so. Is there a better way of expressing this?

Comment: I think its fine if you want to emphasize the mapping.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes, that's the main ideal. The emphasis is on the mapping. Thanks.